# ASP.NET MVC: how do I stop multiple posts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

Is it possible to stop multiple posts of a form by the user click the button over again?

I have tried the PRG pattern, which is great but users can still click the button over and over and have multiple submissions.

I know I can add a JQuery fix, but I want something more robust in the back end.

Does anyone have any solutions? Does the validate anti forgery token functionality solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Anti forgery token is to prevent session hijacking, it wont help you for this. As you already said, you could do a jQuery fix by keeping a count variable and using `preventDefault`

If you want something robust in the backend, then really you need to check if the user has submitted something with the same details moments earlier. It would be a matter of querying your datasource, for an entry by the current user with same data within x timeframe (x being a time constrain determined by how strict you want to be).

Personally, I would handle this in the front-end. I would keep the count, use preventDefault and maybe even disable the button after submit. Then maybe re-enable it once content changes in a form textbox or something. A check that assures something changed before allowing another submit.